# Remote form won't find ID for association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

My program has a `WorkOrder` that `:has_many` `LineItems`. I have a partial `(/views/line_items/_add_line_item.html.erb)` rendered into `WorkOrder#Show (/views/work_orders/show.html.erb)` with `remote true`. However, when submitting the form, the post fails because `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find WorkOrder with 'id'=)`. What am I doing wrong here?

/controllers/line_items_controller.rb#Create

```
def create
  @work_order = WorkOrder.find(params[:work_order_id])
  @line_item = @work_order.line_items.build(line_item_params)
  respone_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @work_order, notice: 'added line item' }
      format.js
    else
      redirect_to @work_order
    end
  end
end
```

/controllers/line_items_controller.rb#line_item_params

```
def line_item_params
  params.permit(:line_item, :description, :quantity, :price_adjustment, :work_order_id)
end
```

/controllers/work_orders_controller.rb#Show

```
def show
  @line_items = @work_order.line_items
  @new_line_item = @work_order.line_items.new
end
```

/views/work_orders/show.html.erb

```
[...]
<%= render 'line_items/add_line_item', wo: @work_order %>
[...]
```

/views/line_items/_add_line_item.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@new_line_item, remote: true) do |form| %>

    <%= form.collection_select(:inventory_sku_id, Inventory::SKU.all, :id, :descriptive_id) %>

    <%= form.text_field :description, id: :line_item_description %>

    <%= form.number_field :quantity, id: :line_item_quantity %>

    <%= form.hidden_field :work_order_id, id: :work_order_id, value: wo.id %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit "New Item" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Console output when creating new line:

```
[INFO ] === Processing by LineItemsController#create as JS
[INFO ]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "line_item"=>{"inventory_sku_id"=>"1", "description"=>"Test", "quantity"=>"2", "work_order_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"New Item"}
[DEBUG] Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :line_item, :commit
[DEBUG]   WorkOrder Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "work_orders".* FROM "work_orders" WHERE "work_orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[INFO ] Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
[FATAL] ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find WorkOrder with 'id'=):
[FATAL] app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:31:in `create'
```

Comment: Can you post the params received at create? And line_item_params?

Comment: @Pablo Sorry this is so late, an... event kept me from the desk. Posted.\

Answer (score 0):

Are your models nested? Change your form to:

```
<%= form_for(wo, @new_line_item, remote: true) do |form| %>
```

**EDIT**

Change your line_item_params to require :line_item

```
def line_item_params
  params.require(:line_item).permit(:description, :quantity, :price_adjustment, :work_order_id, :inventory_sku_id)
end
```

Comment: No I opted against nesting for this one. I had tried this earlier, but it certainly did try to `post` to `work_orders_line_items_path`. Thanks for taking the time, @Pablo, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing parms[:work_order_id] for line_item_params[:work_order_id]? Usually when sanitizing the params this is how you would access your model data.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I'm having the same issue, and beginning to wonder if it's because rails is spitting out that `line_item:` is not a permitted parameter? But that's the object... I'm beginning to lose it :)

Comment: Make sure LineItem belongs_to WorkOrder, otherwise I believe work_order_id won't be a permitted parameter. Hope that helps